# How can I add objects Cbook to my class CBooks without using lists

Tags: c#

Cbooks has an atribute "CTeam[] Teams" and it is of fixed size (8). If I want to add objects to it using this in the Main:

```
    CBook A1 = new CBook("Title1", "Author1");
    CBook A2 = new CBook("Title1", "Author2");

    CBooks ArrayOfBooks = new CBooks(8);
    ArrayOfBooks.Add(A1);
    ArrayOfBooks.Add(A2);
```

then position 0 and 1 are ocuppied, and the positions from 2 to 7 are null. What I want to do is, using a variable "int aux=0", count the ocupied positions like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfTeams; k++)
                {
                    if (Teams[k].Name=="")
                        Aux += 1;
                }
```

So, Aux in this case would be 2, then I want to do "Teams[Aux] = A" so that A would be in the position 2 and now I should have three objects in my array. But I'm getting "Index out of bound"

Comment: What is the code of `CBooks` class specially its `Add` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation then should look similar to this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Element a = new Element("A");
        Element b = new Element("B");

        MyArray array = new MyArray(8);

        array.Add(a);
        array.Add(b);

        Console.WriteLine(array.Count()); //2 Elements are in the array
    }
}

//Sample element class.
public class Element{

    public readonly String MyString;

    public Element(String myString){
     MyString = myString;   
    }
}

//Sample array class.
public class MyArray{

    private readonly Element[] myArray;
    private int count; //Use a property here

    public MyArray(int size){
        //Be careful -> check if size is >= 0.
        myArray = new Element[size];
    }

    public bool Add(Element element){
        if(myArray.Length == count) // return false if no more elements fit.
            return false;

            myArray[count] = element;
            count++;

        return true;
    }

    public int Count(){
     return count;   
    }

}
```

So there is no need for creating an extra count loop. Your "count" variable in "MyArray" class holds always the correct value.
Anyway the implementation or use case of this code is a little bit clunky.
Why are you cant use directly a more safe list or something. That would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need CBooks for? From what I understand, it's just an array of 8 CBook objects so why not use CBook[]?

```
CBook A1 = new CBook("Title1", "Author1");
CBook A2 = new CBook("Title1", "Author2");

CBooks[] ArrayOfBooks = new CBook[8];
ArrayOfBooks[0] = A1;
ArrayOfBooks[1] = A2;

int aux = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < ArrayOfBooks.Length; k++)
{
    //break the loop because we know there are no more books
    if (ArrayOfBooks[k] == null)
        break;
    aux++;
}
```

The question doesn't cover what the variables NumberOfTeams and Teams are for but could those be added to the implementation of CBook?

Comment: With this implementation for counting you have a problem with the correctness ;)
What if you have the following:

ArrayOfBooks[0] = A1;
ArrayOfBooks[1] = A2;
ArrayOfBooks[3] = A3; // or something.

Your loop counts only 2 elements not 3 causing by the early "break".
So you need something like:
for(...){
...
if(ArrayOfBooks[k] != null)
aux++;
...
}